# Is there a library in erlang for X9.63 Key Derivation Function

Tags: erlang, kdf, session-keys

Can somebody please tell me whether there is a library in Erlang for X9.63 Key Derivation Function.  I need to generate the keyData and the Session Keys.

Comment: You have better luck to try this kind of open question on the erlang mailing list http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/. Stackoverflow has very strict set of requirement regarding questions. For details see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (btw I did not vote to close your question)

Comment: thanks for the guide.